# How to scale data between -1 and 1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scaling, normalizing

[image]

[image]

Hi guys! Could somebody please help me with this. bh_df is the data set I am working with. As you can see now the data is between approx. 79 and 77. I need to scale it between -1 and 1. Thank you in advance! I wanted to do x_max-x_min thing (advised here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), but my min data point is 0, so I do not think it will do anything useful.

Comment: Look into `sklearn's` [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

Comment: Consider copying the code instead of sharing screenshots.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do so, you need a function that transforms your data so that

```
x_new = (x - min_x)  / (max_x - min_x)
```

---

**Using pandas**

```
df = df.apply(lambda x:(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)), axis = 0)
```

---

**Using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
normalised_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

As as side note, if the data is supposed to be fed to a ML model, you should call [`fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit) on training and [`transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.transform) over test and validation sets.

Comment: Thank you! I tried  the sklearn. It says MinMaxScaler is not defined.
import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

# bh = blister height
wavelength = 532.0 #nm
# Sets bh_df as the phase difference dataframe
bh_df = A_df.copy()
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
normalised_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)
# Changes from phase difference to path length difference
bh_df["CH1"] = (wavelength/(2*np.pi))*A_df["CH1"]
...

Comment: @GoodDay Try to do the import as shown in my answer. I can’t read the code to be 100% though. Update your question and share the code there

Comment: I edited the code (updated my question). I am not sure what you mean by "share the code there – Giorgos Myrianthous" as I could not find a place to share it on your profile.

Comment: Thank you for your help! One last thing. How to get rid of the blue line (see my updated question)? Thank you!

Comment: @GoodDay If you have a different problem, please ask a new question instead of asking too many questions in a single thread.